Why does 'to' only work in the second sentence?

don't make me wait.
you don't want me to wait.

Why does "to" work in 2 but not in 1?
I need some help explaining this to my friend learning English 

Good question, which I've never really thought about. I think that some verbs are followed by to+infinitive (I want to come, I choose to come). Other verbs are followed by a bare infinitive (Don't make me come, Please let me come.) As to which verbs follow which pattern, you probably just have to learn the lists.

@PeterKirkpatrick If you want to answer a question, please write an answer. Comments are for comments only, for example to request clarification, not for answering questions.

Using "to infinitive" and "bare infinitive.

1.Don't make me wait.
2.You don't want me to wait.
Why does "to" work in 2 but not in 1?

In sentence 1, "wait" is a bare infinitive which follows the main verb "make".
In sentence 2, "to wait" is a "to infinitive", which follows the main verb "want".
Your friend has to master these three lists of main verbs in order to become an expert in the usage of the bare infinitive and to infinitive:
1.Main verbs followed by "bare infinitive".
2.Main verbs followed by "to infinitive".
3.Main verbs followed by both "bare infinitive" and "to infinitive".
I. Main verbs followed by bare infinitive..
Ref. english-today.com.

These are the rules of using bare infinitive:
1.After auxiliary modal verbs :.
(will, shall, would, could, can, may, might, must, should, needn't).
2.After the causative verbs.
'make', 'have', 'let' and 'help':
(‘help’ can also be used with ‘to’).
3..After verbs of perception:.
(see, watch, notice, observe, feel, hear…).
4.After ‘would rather’, ‘had better’:
5.After prepositions such as ‘except’, ‘but’ and ‘than’:

II. Main verbs followed by to infinitive
Here's a list of rules for using "to" infinitives:
1.Verbs of intention and purpose..
- want, need, plan, intend, hope, wish, aim, try, attempt, etc.
2.Verbs of ability and capacity..
- can, could, be able to, be capable of, etc.
3.Verbs of permission and obligation..
- allow, permit, enable, require, obligate, etc.
4.Verbs of preference and desire:.
- prefer, desire, wish, long, yearn, etc.
5.Verbs of expectation and prediction..
- expect, predict, forecast, anticipate, etc.
6.Verbs of recommendation and advice:.
- recommend, suggest, advise, propose, etc.
III. Main verbs with both bare and to infinitive.
Here's a list of verbs that can take both bare infinitives and "to" infinitives :
1.Help
- Bare: "Help me do it." (assistance).
- To: "Help me to understand." (enable).
2.See
- Bare: "See it!" (perception).
- To: "See it to be true." (understand).
3.Hear:
- Bare: "Hear me!" (perception).
- To: "Hear it to believe it."  (understand).
4.Feel:.
- Bare: "Feel it!" (sensation).
- To: "Feel it to be true." (understand).
5.Know :.
- Bare: "Know it!" (familiarity).
- To: "Know it to be true."     (understand).
6.Make :.
- Bare: "Make him do it." (causative).
- To: "Make it to the meeting." (attend).
7.Let :.
- Bare: "Let them go." (permission).
- To: "Let it to someone else." (allow).
8.Have :.
- Bare: "Have him do it." (causative).
- To: "Have it to eat." (possess).
9.watch :.
- Bare: "Watch it!" (perception).
- To: "Watch it to understand." (study).
10.Notice:.
- Bare: "Notice it!" (perception).
- To: "Notice it to be true." (understand)



don't make me wait
you don't want me to wait


The verb types in the two examples are different.
The first one is a construction with causative verb make.
The second example is of
matrix clause + 'to-infinitive' non-finite clause
Causative verbs include those followed by bare infinitives, and those followed by to-infinitives;  make is an an example of the former.
Promova explains:

Using "Make": When someone forces another person to do something. The structure is: [Subject] + make + [person] + [base form of verb]. Example: "The teacher made the student apologize."


Using "Have": When someone arranges for someone else to do something. The structure is: [Subject] + have + [person] + [base form of verb]. Example: "She had the mechanic fix her car."


Using "Get": When someone persuades another person to do something. The structure is: [Subject] + get + [person] + to + [base form of verb]. Example: "I got my brother to lend me his laptop."

Edit
Two other common causative verbs are allow (used with to-infinitives) and let (used with bare infinitives).
We may need to learn the usage of these verbs by getting more exposure to them.

Your answer explains well the two patterns, but if I was an English language learner, how would I know which causative verbs follow which pattern?

Thanks, @Peter Kirkpatrick.  I've added two more verbs and explained further.

Except in the English of the King James bible. "He maketh me to lie down in green pastures"

Thanks, @TimR. Yes, Google Books shows a list.

Google Books

@PeterKirkpatrick: which particular kinds of complement a verb takes is part of the lexical properties of the verb, which have to be learnt alongside its meaning, pronunciation, spelling, etc. There are some patterns, but they do not reliably specify this. As an example, advise and suggest have very similar meanings, but they take different kinds of complement: suggest takes a noun phrase or a that clause as direct object, whereas advise takes the recipient as direct object, and an infinitive clause as indirect object. (There are other possibilities I haven't mentioned)
