Catenative verbs with bare infinitive
The verb “notice” is a catenative verb that is followed by a bare infinitive. Therefore, this sentence:
1–“She noticed her wig was askew.”
Should be:
2–“She noticed her wig be askew.”
Is sentence number two correct?

(2) seems old fashioned to my UK eyes. (1) works well.

I. "notice" is stative catenative verb..
The verb "notice" is a stative catenative verb.
Ref.Cambridge dictionary

stative
a verb that describes a state rather than an action:

In the case of "notice", it's a stative verb because it describes a state of awareness or perception, rather than an action. Yet, it can still form chains with other verbs,
Other examples of stative catenative verbs include "see", "hear", and "feel", which can also form chains with other verbs while describing states or conditions.
II. Showing the catenative property of "notice"..

The verb “notice” is a catenative verb that is followed by a bare infinitive. Therefore, this sentence:
1–“She noticed her wig was askew.”.
Should be:
2–“She noticed her wig be askew.”.
Is sentence number two correct?

Sentence 2 is  grammatically incorrect.
***It is possible to illustrate the catenative property of "notice" by modifying the sentence as below:
1.She noticed her wig go askew.
2.She noticed her wig fall off.
3.She noticed her wig slip off.
These sentences use the bare infinitives - go, fall, slip.

Thank you for explaining the difference.

@Piermo This is related topic explaining bare infinitive
https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/356626/why-does-to-only-work-in-the-second-sentence#356658

Thank you for the link.

I would say that sentence 2 is ungrammatical: it is certainly not idiomatic.
The reason that sentence 1 is grammatical is that notice can take a "that" clause, and the "that" can be omitted, so it is equivalent to

She noticed that her wig was askew.

I'm not sure what makes 2 ungrammatical (or at any rate, dubious). I suspect that notice cannot take an infinitive clause with a stative verb, but I haven't explored it very far. Note that:

He noticed her look at John. (non-stative look)

but

? He noticed her look guilty. (stative look)

Edit: it occurs to me that if I met He noticed her look guilty, I would interpret it as inchoative, not stative: her expression changed, and she started to look guilty.

He noticed her look at John: If you asked me to parse that sentence I would label look as a noun. Compare He noticed her looking at John.

It works for me as a verb, not a noun, because I would not expect the noun to take at: I'd expect towards or something.

Thank you for your answer.
